# What chording keyboard software is available?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for a chording software for ubuntu. For using chorded combinations for typing only with one hand.

I'm fairly certain one exists because I read about it a couple months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug this up [gkos](http://gkos.com/gkos/linux/)
it looks like it can use the custom keyboard, or keys on a regular keyboard.
this looks promising, [gkos_for_linux](http://gkos.com/gkos/linux/gkos_for_linux.html)

then there is joy2chord that uses joystick buttons, hmmm
[joy2chord](http://joy2chord.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @Mathew thanks for the links, I'm going to look into gkos

Comment: Please do report back if you find anything useful, or answer your own question with a tutorial if you eventually solved this yourself.